# MPNS - Disconnected state; how to reconnect

Tags: xml, windows-phone-8, push-notification, mpns

We haven't changed anything to our backends, but suddenly the MPNS messages are not working any more.

the request from MS is:

```
X-DeviceConnectionStatus: Disconnected X-NotificationStatus: Received X-SubscriptionStatus: Active
```

Does anybody know how to *reconnect* my device?

The phone also gets weird errors, if I want to open mail.google.com - certificate issues… No updates are available for the phone; The phone is used only in WiFi

opening a non SSL site is working fine!

Cheers.kg

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I'm not sure why, but putting in a SIM card solved my problem. 15 minutes after having a SIM inserted a bunch of MPNS messages were arriving and now the sate is **connected** again!

hope this helps you as well.

Cheers.kg